# Constructor annotated with Jackson @JsonCreator not being called in POJO?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I am working with a web service that stores POJOs in a MongoDB. I want to make use of Mongo's 'expireAfterSeconds' time to live feature, to clear out old documents in my collection after a certain period of time.

Initially I had an implementation that sent the date to the REST service using the following JSON:

`{
  "testIndex": "testIndex",
  "name": "hello",
  "date": "2016-05-09T11:00:39.639Z"
}`

The above code created the document in the collection, and with the following annotation, deleted the document after 10 seconds.

```
@Indexed (expireAfterSeconds=10)
private Date date;
```

After implementing this code, I decided I wanted to generate the date only on the Java side, meaning the JSON is now as follows:

`{
  "testIndex": "testIndex",
  "name": "hello"
}`

Then I have a constructor in the POJO using JsonCreator from Jackson

```
@JsonCreator
public TTLTestVO (@JsonProperty("testIndex") String testIndex, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.testIndex = testIndex;
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    this.name = name;
}
```

From reading the documentation [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) I believe this should flag the constructor to be used when creating a new object. The testIndex and name fields are populated as before. However with this implementation, each time I check the document in my mongo the date value is 'null'. If I change the text for one of the string values to 'hello from the constructor', the constructor appears not to be called as the initial text contained in the JSON is what is added to the database.

POJO

`

@Document(collection = "test")public class TTLTestVO {

```
@Id private String _id;

@Indexed
private String testIndex;

@Indexed (expireAfterSeconds=10)
private Date createdAt;

private String name;

@JsonIgnore
public TTLTestVO() {
    // default
}

@JsonCreator
public TTLTestVO (@JsonProperty("testIndex") String testIndex, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.testIndex = "hello from the constructor";
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTestIndex() {
    return testIndex;
}

public void setTestIndex(String testIndex) {
    this.testIndex = testIndex;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.createdAt = date;
}
`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After investigating some more I discovered the issue lies with the Spring Framework implementation of @JsonCreator - I removed the imports for `org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` and replaced them with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`. The above implementation now functions as expected.

I have been unable to find an explanation online as to why the spring version isn't working, so if anyone has any ideas please let me/ others know